# How do I Troubleshoot Labeling Issues in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have been working on a visualizations for a project I am working on. I keep running into trouble with the labels, specifically subtitles and captions. Every time I let these labels or the theme for these elements, they do not appear in the final plot.

Here is my code:

```
earnyears <- as.data.table(ACS_LI[ACS_LI$Fulltime == 1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & ACS_LI$Immigrant == 1, list(
  "Total Median Earnings" = weighted.median(ACS_LI$INCEARN[ACS_LI$Fulltime ==1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & Immigrant == 1], 
ACS_LI$PERWT[ACS_LI$Fulltime == 1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0]),
  "Less than 5 Years" = weighted.median(ACS_LI$INCEARN[ACS_LI$Fulltime ==1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & Immigrant == 1 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 == 1], 
ACS_LI$PERWT[ACS_LI$Fulltime == 1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 ==1]),
  "5-10 Years" = weighted.median(ACS_LI$INCEARN[ACS_LI$Fulltime ==1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & Immigrant == 1 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 == 2], 
ACS_LI$PERWT[ACS_LI$Fulltime == 1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 ==2]),
  "More than 10 Years" = weighted.median(ACS_LI$INCEARN[ACS_LI$Fulltime ==1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & Immigrant == 1 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 == 3], 
ACS_LI$PERWT[ACS_LI$Fulltime == 1 & ACS_LI$INCEARN >0 & ACS_LI$yrs3_1 ==3])
)])

#Make a bar graph 
median_earnings <- mean(earnyears_longer$`Total Median Earnings`)

earnyears_longer <- earnyears%>%
                         pivot_longer(-c(`Total Median Earnings`), names_to = "Years_in_US", values_to = "Median_Income")

earnyears_plot <- ggplot(aes(x = Years_in_US, y = Median_Income), data = earnyears_longer)+
  geom_bar(width = 0.75,position = "dodge", stat = "identity", fill = "#1f78b4")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = median_earnings,
             color = "#fdbf6f",
             linetype = "dashed") +
  ggplot2::annotate("text", 
                    x = 1.125, y = 66500, 
                    label = "Median Earnings: $64,993.50",
                    color = "#fdbf6f")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "#d9d9d9"),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "#d9d9d9", 
                                        linetype = "dashed"),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", face = "bold", size = (15), hjust = 0, vjust = 1),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12)),
      axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12)),
      axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (10)),
      axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Arial", size = (12)),
      plot.caption.position = c("bottom", "left"))+
  labs(title = "Median Earnings for Immigrants", 
       subtitle = "By Time in the United States", 
       caption = "Source: ACS 2019, 5-Year Sample. Numbers in 2019 Dollars.",
       x = "Years in the US", 
       y = "Median Earnings")

ggplotly(earnyears_plot)
```

[And here is the resulting plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50PHQ.png)

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: ggplot subtitles and captions are not supported by `ggplotly` but require some manual work. See [How do I keep my subtitles when I use ggplotly()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923256/how-do-i-keep-my-subtitles-when-i-use-ggplotly) for a related post and option fix the subtitle.

Comment: @stefan, thank you so much! This was a huge help.